# Extract near matches from longer string

Tags: r, string-matching, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to extract near matches from a string, where the pattern is misspelled.
Looking for the phrase "Se abre la sesión"

Here's a reproducible example.

```
pattern <- "Se abre la sesión"

text <- "Al ingresar a la aplicación, el usuario debe proporcionar sus credenciales de acceso. Si las credenciales son correctas, se abra la sesión y el usuario puede empezar a utilizar la aplicación."
```

I've tried this:

```
matches <- agrepl("Se abre la sesión", text, ignore.case = TRUE, max.distance = 3)
spelling <- str_extract(text[matches], "Se abre la sesión")
```

and this:

```
library(stringdist)
matches <- which(stringdist(text, "Se abre la sesión", method = "lv", useBytes = TRUE) <= 3)
match_text <- substr(text, matches, matches + nchar("Se abre la sesión") - 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `aregexec` with `regmatches` to *extract near matches from a string*.

```
regmatches(text,
    aregexec("Se abre la sesión", text, ignore.case = TRUE, max.distance = 3))
#[[1]]
#[1] "se abra la sesión"
```